# Rotating texture node with non-uniform scale

Tags: materials, vector-mapping

I've been working on a procedural material and I'm having some trouble with vector mappings. When rotating a vector with a uniform scale it works as I'd expect

[image: uniform scale]

But when I scale in just one axis I get this result, I was expecting that the diagonal shape would have remained while the range between opposite corners increased. It's like the nodes are being applied in reverse order.

[image: non-uniform scale]

**Is there a simple way that I can scale a vector *before* rotating it without having this happen? like this  (but without having to rotate the object)**

[image: rotated vector]

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, just swap nodes like this:

[image]

The reason why it works like this, you have not vectors, but instead you have a triple value on every point on geometry. If you think like this, you will understand the logic.

Comment: So, you're saying that there *isn't* a way to scale first, *then* rotate and achieve the above effect? That's unfortunate, the node setup I was aiming for relied upon the rotation being at the end of the chain.